# Keytool error : Keystore was tampered with... Special characters

Tags: java, encoding, keystore, keytool

I know there are already a few posts about this error, but I couldn't find an answer fitting my problem :

I created an AES key with the following command :

```
keytool -genseckey -alias TEST -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storepass "a#b$c<d>" 
-storetype JCEKS -keystore /usr/my/path/test.jck
```

I then try to access the keystore from java code :

```
String password = "a#b$c<d>";

char[] passwordChars= password.toCharArray(); 

// loading the file containing the key
InputStream inputStreamFichierCle;
try {
    inputStreamFichierCle = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    keyStore.load(inputStreamFichierCle, passwordChars);
}
```

And there I get an `IOException : keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect`.

Note that I tried with normal password (ex : pass) and this works perfectly, so I guess the problem here has to do with the special characters I use in my password.

**What is happening, and how can I fix this?**

Comment: The usual technique is to use `String.toCharArray()` instead of that loop.

Comment: Thx, edited the post but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cause of this problem is the dollar sign in combination with bash command line.

Basically "$c" is substituted with the content of a variable with the name "c". Unfortunately there is no variable with this name, so it is replaced with an empty string.

You can avoid the variable substitution by using [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash). See the difference:

```
$ echo "a#b$c<d>"
a#b<d>
$ echo 'a#b$c<d>'
a#b$c<d>
```

If you use the password "`a#b<d>`" in your java code, it will work.

Comment: you saved me from another wasted day! Thank you!

Comment: My keyPassword also contained a "\$n" part. Using this password always caused this error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key.
I removed the backslash in this password and the password worked!

Comment: @GedankenNebel Good point, the escape character "\" also removes the special meaning from the "$" like single quotes do, so the $ is part of the password, but because the \ itself is a special character, it is missing in the resulting password.

Comment: @GedankenNebel That's why it is recommended to use single quotes instead. You can then put any character in the password and nothing changes unexpectedly.